# mysql: see all open connections to a given database?

Tags: mysql, database

With administrative permissions im mysql, how can I see all the open connections to a specific db in my server?

Answer (score 210, accepted):

The command is

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST
```

Unfortunately, [it has no narrowing parameters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-processlist.html). If you need them you can do it from the command line:

```
mysqladmin processlist | grep database-name
```

Comment: `mysqladmin -i 1 processlist` to refresh the output every second.

Comment: if you need to authenticate
`mysqladmin --user=[USERNAME] --password=[PASSWORD] -i 1 processlist`

Comment: @TomJenkinson I usually don't use it because I don't want the password to appear in the command line history or in the process list (ps aux)

Comment: As an alternate to @chanux, with a slightly cleaner output imho `watch -n1 mysqladmin processlist`

Answer (score 74):

As well you can use:

```
mysql> show status like '%onn%';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| Aborted_connects         | 0     |
| Connections              | 303   |
| Max_used_connections     | 127   |
| Ssl_client_connects      | 0     |
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates | 0     |
| Ssl_finished_connects    | 0     |
| Threads_connected        | 127   |
+--------------------------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Feel free to use
[Mysql-server-status-variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html) or [Too-many-connections-problem](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html)

Comment: It's case insensitive anyway, Why `%onn%` instead of `%conn%`?

Comment: Sure you can use %conn% instead of %onn%. And yes, mostly it's case insensitive. For case sensitivity please see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: This shows statistical/historical data. The question is about currently open connections.

Answer (score 44):

That should do the trick for the newest MySQL versions:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE DB like "%DBName%";
```

Comment: This is the only one correct, apart from the chosen one, which can be done using SQL instead of `mysqladmin`.

Answer (score 11):

You can invoke MySQL ***show status command***

> show status like 'Conn%';

For more info read [Show open database connections](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/mysql/how-show-open-database-connections-mysql)

Comment: Sorry, but this solution shows only one value. I prefer the command "show status like '%onn%';" which is in the same referred web page.

Comment: @RaulLuna, It's case insensitive anyway, Why `%onn%` instead of `%conn%`?

Comment: @Pacerier It's more than that: it is just in case the "connection" word appear as part of a larger word (max_used_connections, for instance). Of course you can use show status like '%conn%'

Comment: @RaulLuna, If the  "connection" word appear as part of a larger word, both `%onn%` and `%conn%` will still work. No difference.

Comment: @Pacerier: yes, you are rigth.

Comment: why is this marked up? it does not show the current open connections.

Answer (score 7):

In MySql,the following query shall show the total number of open connections:

```
show status like 'Threads_connected';
```

Answer (score 6):

SQL:
show full processlist;

This is what the MySQL Workbench does.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running a *nix system, also consider [mytop](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/).

To limit the results to one database, press "d" when it's running then type in the database name.

Comment: Isn't this app also using `show processlist` internally?

Comment: I believe it does.  mytop just presents the information neatly with filtering options.  I've made a lot of good use of it in the past while analysing performance issues.  Also, it's quicker in emergencies to log on to a machine, run mytop and immediately see what's going on.  Much like running "top".

Comment: By using more components, you're exposing yourself to more bugs. Since `show processlist`'s output satisfices, why would you need `mytop` for?

Comment: Why use "top" when "ps aux" satisfices?

Answer (score 2):

From the monitoring context here is how you can easily view the connections to all databases sorted by database. With that data easily monitor.

```
SELECT DB,USER,HOST,STATE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST ORDER BY DB DESC;
```

```
+------+-------+---------------------+-----------+
| DB   | USER  | HOST                | STATE     |
+------+-------+---------------------+-----------+
| web  | tommy | 201.29.120.10:41146 | executing |
+------+-------+---------------------+-----------+
```

If we encounter any hosts hots max connections and then not able to connect, then we can reset host tables by flushing it and is as follows:

```
FLUSH HOSTS;
```

Answer (score 0):

In query browser right click on database and select processlist

Comment: This is specific to a client.