# php - MySQL Error 1040 "Too many connections"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, error-handling, try-catch

I have this error, I have seen on several pages how to fix it, increasing the max connections variable, but I was wondering if there is any way to retry connecting 'n' number of times before throwing that error,
I am using mysqli to create my connection.

I would be very grateful for any help you could give me to get an idea of ​​how to do it if possible

update

con.php

```
<?php $con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "grmv"); 
if($conexion->connect_errno) {
die ("Error: " . $con->connect_errno . "---" . $con->connect_error);
}
return $con;
?>


 Products.php
<?php
            include"con.php";
           mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
            $result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from bio, carac where idprod=5");
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
....
}
$conexion->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: can you atleast post the code for us to understand where the problem is? from this what can we understand?

Comment: It would be better if you showed us your code so we can identify if you are generating multiple unnecessary connections

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm guessing you always reconnect for every query you make so the solution is not increasing the amount of connections but, maintaining your connections, closing unnecessary ones. - have to see the code though.

Comment: Here is the code, I search in the database the characteristics of the product to display in a table are about 40-50 products

Comment: @GeorgeDryser 
I think that's the problem because I use that query on all products how I could solve it?

Comment: Are you on an shared host? How much connection do you already have permitted? I would suggest to use aother user then 'root' to access your database. And finally, just for the heck of it check how much table are still 'opened' `http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.stat.php` and this might be relevant to you if you have proper permission on the system => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620662/mysql-see-all-open-connections-to-a-given-database#1620915

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier 101 connection and i will read that

Comment: And do you consider 101 being 'normal' according to your traffic? If you have high traffic you might consider raising he bar a little more (and definitivly change the user accesing the DB) .On the other hand, if you are on Dev and you are the only one running the code then i think you should continue your investigation. Wish i could help you more, i had this problem in the pasted but got lucky and an update/restart fixed it.

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier 
Yes it is high traffic, I would like to increase the maximum number of connections but I could not communicate with my host provider, so I was looking for another solution as if I could use a sleep () if it finds that error and make the attempt to reconnect, A maximum of 5 attempts before launching that error but I do not know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

More consistent way is to keep using OOP aproach, also good practice to use bind for any untrusted input, maybe not here specifically but still good practice.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(
            $connectionData['DB_HOST'],
            $connectionData['DB_USER'],
            $connectionData['DB_PASSWORD'],
            $connectionData['DB_NAME']
        );
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select * from bio, carac where idprod=?");
$stmt->bind_param('5');
$stmt->execute();
while ($result = $stmt->fetch()) {
       // do stuff     
}

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question and no inputs from outside goes in the query so statement is not mandatory in this particular case. Nice try.

Comment: $stmt->close(); was the key difference here, not the binding as I mentioned. "Nice try" apparently adds nothing to conversation.